# max mysql queries per minute

Tags: mysql, performance

How many queries does the slave can handle per minute?

In my case, I used the show status like '%questions%' and found that after the interval of 1 minute, around 5,000 queries were executed.

Is it the normal behavior or it can improved?

Comment: The thing you want to worry is the query speed instead of how many query in 1 minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many inter-related factors which influence the answer to your questions. They include, but are not limited to

- The distribution of queries to your slave
- The timing and types of updates coming in via replication
- Your dataset
- Your hardware
- Your MySQL version and engines being employed

Having said that, the stat of "5000 `question`s per minute" by itself it not sufficient to raise any flags in my books.

It might be more worthwhile to determine if your application is operating within an acceptable range; e.g. what the application's average response time or worst case response time.

It's worth noting that the `question`s counter includes more than just `SELECT`s. I can't find a comprehensive list or reference, but, for some examples, I believe that "`UPDATE`s, `DELETE`s, `SHOW STATUS`, `USE` $db, `SHOW TABLES`" all increment the `questions` status variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my server is currently reporting that in the month it's been running it has executed an average of 3,090 queries per *second*, that's 185k per minute. So there's definitely something that could be improved!